# Could the installation of Openwrt firmware at AP turn it to Router

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, openwrt

We plan to purchase [TP-Link WA901ND Access Point](http://www.tp-link.com/eg/products/details/cat-12_TL-WA901ND.html). It is clear from its specifications and the [default firmware emulator](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/EMULATOR_wa901ndv5_eu/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm), it is only AP without any routing features such as QoS, NAT, etc.

We plan also to replace its default firmware with [OpenWRT firmware](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd). The question is: Does all routing features of the OpenWRT firmware will be available to the device after changing its default firmware? In other words, are there any hardware limitations that prevents any access point to work as a wireless router?

Comment: If the device supports OpenWRT then the expected functionality of the supported OpenWRT firmware should work.  OpenWRT is compiled for each device

Comment: @Ramhound The device is supported by OpenWRT. However, as you regarded *`OpenWRT is compiled for each device`*. That 's make me worry about supporting routing features in the OpenWRT for the AP that I regard.

Comment: What restrictions are placed on OpenWRT depend on what revision of the device you have.  The OpenWRT wiki for that device outlines those limitations

Comment: @Ramhound There is no any obvious restrictions other wise some optional physical modifications in what they called "Serial Console" for some revisions. [device's openWRT wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd)

Comment: Luci comes with memory requirements.  I specifically saw a revision of that device that doesnt support Luci

Comment: @Ramhound Ckeckout [this link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd#install_openwrt) It shows that LuCI is included.

Comment: Already read it: “then you will want to configure your router with LuCI: (the v2 AP is not able to support LuCI so skip this section)” might want to read my comment again

Comment: @Ramhound yes, the revision of the device is 3 or above. It is not 2 any way, because the its external shape is not like the shape of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device that only bridges between the AP-mode WNIC and the Ethernet NIC is doing significantly less work per-packet than a device that does NAPT, and could conceivably get away with a slower CPU, less RAM, and less FlashROM space than a device that does NAT or other "home gateway" features.

So while putting OpenWrt (I guess we should say LEDE now since LEDE has replaced OpenWrt) on your AP device will give it the gateway features it currently lacks, it's quite possible it will come at a cost of reduced throughput.

Comment: Depending on the revision of the hardware, this particular device, might be very challenging to configure. Specific versions don’t even support the web GUI, LUCI, attempting to figure OpenWRT is hard enough doing it over ssh is even more difficult.

Comment: From the side of resources, I think that it will be sufficient because our network is very tiny i.e not more than estimated 6 or 7 devices will use it at the same time, additionally, the device regarded has 32 MB RAM, and CPU at more than 450 MHz. However, just knowing it may work as a router is very fine for us.

Comment: OpenWrt and LEDE have merged back, using the openwrt name.